# CountDownTimer does not run after binding to a service

Tags: android

After I Bind to a service inside the

```
onServiceConnected()
```

method I start a `CountDownTimer`. The problem is that the timer does not start counting down.  I have gone through with the debugger and sure enough it is executing the method that starts the Timer.

If I use a button to start the timer it works!  What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible `onServiceConnected()` is being fired too early or something. Try calling `postDelayed()` on your `CountDownTimer`, supplying a `Runnable` that starts the `CountDownTimer` and a delay of, say, 250ms.

Comment: Worked nicely. I used a Handler to run postDelayed() is that the best way to go?

Comment: If you already had a Handler, sure. However, `postDelayed()` is also on `View` (of which `CountDownTimer` is a subclass), so you don't need a `Handler` just for `postDelayed()`.